# Why ch showing value 26723

Tags: c

[image: Why ch value showing 26723? Where ch=26723 came from is it Garbage or any other ?]

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
 char ch,aa;// variable ch
 printf("%d",'ch');//ch value
 scanf("%c",aa);
```

}

In the output why ch=26723.where it came from ? If i changed to dh the value changes to 26724

Comment: Ch is a variable. 'X' is a char, and "str" present a string. In your code, 'ch' does not mean ch variable.

Comment: what is the question? do you try to display ch variable content? do you wonder why passing multiple caracters instead of single caracter works? do you want to understand why you get 0x6863 instead of 0x6368 (endianess problem?)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not printing the variable `ch`, but a multicharacter literal `'ch'` which happens to have a value of 26723. `'dh'` happens to have a value of 27624.

If you want to print the variable `char ch`, you must first initialize it to a value and then print it using the correct printf specifier:

```
char ch = 'A';
printf( "%c" , ch );
```

Comment: But the question is if 'c'=99d why 'ch'=26723d ? @this

Comment: It is not anonymous value because always 'ch'=26723d

Comment: @MdShibbirHossen Multicharacter literal is a compiler extension. That compiler defined it to be that particular value when evaluated as an int. Sorry I don't understand the second comment.

Comment: oh yes . i thought it is like an ascii values

Answer (score 1):

The value is more understandable when you print it as hexadecimal.  Using my [`hex`](http://invisible-island.net/misc_tools/index.html#item:hex) utility:

```
$ hex 26723 26724
26723: 26723 064143 0x6863 text "hc" utf8 \346\241\243
26724: 26724 064144 0x6864 text "hd" utf8 \346\241\244
```

I can see that `26723` is formed by the characters `c` and `h` (with allowances for byte-ordering).

A similar comment can be made for `26724`.

Comment: is there any chart for this multi-character literal.(e.g. ascii chart i.e c=99). Also how do i find the value for multicharacter literal. ?

Comment: Probably there is no table: it would be very long.  The compiler generates the values for the multicharacter literal, in any case.